# Excel Copy From WB to another WB and other

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently looking for a code to improve my Dashboard. Actually, I need to know how to simplify and make my code more efficient. It's working but It's longer and longer day after day because of the amount of data/traffic at certain hours on the company network. 
I know it's not correct to use "Select" but I didn't find an answer to my problem.

Situation:

1. I created my layout on SAP, and I export them (default file name is
   'Export.xls')
2. I go to my Main Excel File (called 'Dashboard') and I
   run the code from the WS concerned by the layout exported
3. The username need to be captured in case I'm out of office, and someone else need to run the code.
4. When Data are imported from SAP Export to my main file, it closes the SAP "Export" file

This is my current code:

```
Sub PasteSAP()
'
' Pull Data From SAP Export - Excel File
'
Dim UserName As String

UserName = Environ("username")

   'Clear "PasteSAP" sheet in case the next one will have less data
    Range("A:O").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

   'Open SAP Excel file (the export)
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Desktop\export.XLSX"
    Windows("export.XLSX").Activate

    'Copy data of the SAP Excel file
    Range("A:O").Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Go back to the main file and paste in the active worksheet
    Windows("Dashboard - 2017.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A:O").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Close SAP Excel file
    Windows("export.XLSX").Activate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.Close

    'Change Format
    Range("A:A").Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
       End With

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

    For r = 2 To lastRow
        If wks.Cells(r, 1) <> "" Then
        wks.Cells(r, 7).NumberFormat = "General"
        wks.Cells(r, 9).Style = "Currency"
        End If
    Next r

     Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are copying the whole columns you do not Need to erase them beforehand.

Usually you would not want to jump between windows since it takes lots of time.

Also turning off ScreenUpdating could speed things up.

Try the following code:

```
...
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

dim wb_export as Workbook
dim ws_export_from as Worksheet, ws_export_to as Worksheet

Set wb_export = Workbooks.open("...\Export.xls")
Set ws_export_from = wb_export.Worksheets("your worksheet")
Set ws_export_to = Worksheets("Destination worksheet")

ws_export_from.range("A:O").Copy Destination := ws_export_to.Range("A:O")

wb_export.close false
set wb_export = Nothing
set ws_export_from = Nothing
set ws_export_to = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This should run a lot faster.

Comment: So when I'm on my main file, with your code, it will open by itself the Export file, right?
I also erase data first because when people export the layout from SAP, they don't enter the same dates (start/end date). That's why I erase to avoid duplicated data